# Get featured image outside the loop using foreach

Tags: loop, query, php

I'm not familiar with working outside the loop so forgive me if this question has been asked already.

How do I get a featured image of a post that's outside the loop? I did a `print_r` and I didn't see anything related to a featured image.

Any ideas on what to do next?

**Update:** I was able to get it working but I need a way to show every image size associated with the post's featured image.

This is what I've done so far:

```
// the query. Only show posts with a certain taxonomy
<?php $args = array('tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'post-status','field' => 'slug','terms' => array ('post-status-published')))); $query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : $major = false; $major_first = false; $duplicates = []; while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

//check if any post belongs to a certain category
<?php if ( in_category( 'major' ) ) : ?>
    <?php $major = true;?>
    <?php $major_data [] = get_post($post->ID) ;?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( in_category( 'major-first' ) ) : ?>
    <?php $major_first = true;?>
    <?php $major_first_data [] = get_post($post->ID) ;?>
    <?php $image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ),'large' ); $image = $image_array; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

// end of the loop
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

// show content
<?php if ($major == true):?>
    <?php if ($major == true):?>
        <?php foreach($major_first_data as $postID) { ;?>
            <?php $postData = get_post( $postID );?>
            <?php print $postData->post_title;?><br>
            <?php echo $image[0]; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php foreach($major_data as $postID) { ;?>
        <?php $postData = get_post( $postID );?>
        <?php print $postData->post_title;?><br>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This question here might help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121089/get-wp-get-attachment-url-outside-of-loop

Comment: Awesome! Getting there but still have a problem though. How do I show every image associated with the image like thumbnail,media,large,etc or do I have to create a function to every image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by doing the following:

```
<?php foreach($major_first_data as $postID) { ;?>
<?php $postData = get_post( $postID );?>
<?php print $postData->post_title;?><br>
<?php print wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $postID ), 'thumbnail' )[0];?>
<?php } ?>
```

Focusing on the line:

`<?php print wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $postID ), 'thumbnail' )[0];?>`

it outputs the following:

`Array (
    [0] => url to thumbnail 
    [1] => image width
    [2] => image height
    [3] => 1
)`

And it you want to use another size, just substitue `thumbnail` to anything else you want.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to get a list of all available sizes on your site. This function `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` will do that. You can then pass the results of that to `image_get_intermediate_size()` along with the post id and

```
<?php $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes(); ?>
<?php foreach($major_data as $postID) { ;?>
    <?php $postData = get_post( $postID );?>
    <?php print $postData->post_title;?><br>
    <?php var_dump(image_get_intermediate_size( $postID, $sizes )); ?> 
<?php } ?>
```

more info on this function [get_intermediate_image_sizes()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes)

lot of good functions for dealing with images in the [media.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/media.php#L0) wordpress core file